# JPA: multiple select statements while fetching a single record @OneToOne and @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Considering my entities as CPU and PROCESSOR having relationship one to one with shared Primary Key.
One CPU has One Processor.

CPU.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PKJoin_CPUt")
public class CPU {


    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Processor processor;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "cpu", optional = true,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public Processor getProcessor() {
        return processor;
    }
    public void setProcessor(Processor processor) {
        this.processor = processor;
        if (null != processor) {
            processor.setCpu(this);
        }
    }
    private Processor2 processor2;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "cpu", optional = true,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public Processor2 getProcessor2() {
        return processor2;
    }

    public void setProcessor2(Processor2 processor2) {
        this.processor2 = processor2;
        if (null != processor2) {
            processor2.setCpu(this);
        }
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        if (null != processor) {
            processor.setId(id);
        }
        if (null != processor2) {
            processor2.setId(id);
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String deptName) {
        this.name = deptName;
    }

}
```

Processor.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PKJoin_Processor")
public class Processor {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    private CPU cpu;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public CPU getCpu() {
        return cpu;
    }

    public void setCpu(CPU cpu) {
        this.cpu = cpu;
    }
    @Id
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
  static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Hello");
  static EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

  public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    new Main().findData();
   // new Main().persistData();

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    emf.close();    

  }

 public void findData(){      

    CPU cpu = em.find(CPU.class, 449);
    System.out.println(cpu.getProcessor().getName());   


  }
}
```

This is executing like this::

```
    Hibernate: select cpu0_.id as id11_0_, cpu0_.name as name11_0_ from PKJoin_CPUt cpu0_ where cpu0_.id=?
    Hibernate: select processor0_.id as id38_0_, processor0_.name as name38_0_ from  PKJoin_Processor processor0_ where processor0_.id=?
    Hibernate: select processor2x0_.id as id19_0_, processor2x0_.name as name19_0_ from PKJoin_Processor222 processor2x0_ where processor2x0_.id=?
```

Joe

I don't want these three queries to get executed while I am fetching only the CPUName attribute.I don't want join also.
I want only the first query to get executed for whenever i try to fetch CPU attributes.
Need a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that since the associatio is optional, Hibernate has no way to know, just by loading a CPU, if it has an associated processor or not. So, in order to either set the processor field to null, or to set it to an instance of Processor, it has to chck if a processor exists with the primary key of the CPU.

To avoid that, the easiest way is to map the association using a join column in CPU pointing to the processor. That way, if the join column is null, Hibernate knows there is no associated CPU. And if it's not null, it can set the procssor field to a lazy proxy.

Another way, AFAIK, is to use `@LazyToOne(NO_PROXY)`, and to [instrument the bytecode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching-lazyproperties). But I've had bad experiences with this setting in the past. Maybe it has improved.

Comment: But Mr. Nizet, don't you think @JoinColumn will created a new extra column at either side. My situation is like below:

Comment: But Mr. Nizet, don't you think @JoinColumn will created a new extra column at either side. My situation is like below:  1. CPU has Processor1 and CPU has Processor2. 2. I want CPU's PK to become as FK is Processor1 and Processor2 and No extra join column on either side. and I am achieving this also using above code but my problem is that whenever i try to load CPU only , it automatically load Processor1 and Processor2 which is waste of time in aspect of performance optimization. So I am focusing on just to avoid it. @LazyToOne(NO_PROXY) is not working in my case also.Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Yes, of course it will add a column. But it will avoid the extra queries. Decide what you find the most annoying: having an additional column, or having an additional query.

Answer (score 0):

In your findData(), you do cpu.getProcessor().getName(), so it's logical you get a query for the first processor.

You do weird things in the CPU.setId() function, maybe that's why the processors are loaded.

You shouldn't do this, you should let hibernate take care of this. For bidirectional one-to-one relations based on primary key, I think you need the following:

```
public class CPU { 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;


    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "cpu", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Processor processor; 

    ...
}

public class Processor {  
    @Id @OneToOne 
    @JoinColumn("id")
    private CPU cpu;  //combine @Id and @OneToOne, no int id needed.

    protected Processor(){}    

    public Processor(CPU cpu){
       this.cpu = cpu;
       cpu.setProcessor(this);
    }    
    ...
}
```

Now if you save a Processor with a CPU, its id is magically filled in with the CPU's id.
Make sure you save them in the correct order:

```
CPU cpu = new CPU();
em.save(cpu);
Processor p = new Processor(cpu);
em.save(p);
```